# Adding ID to button, but must change based on radio input selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dynamic

**EDITED TO ADD HTML:** not exactly the same since im not in my office anymore, but you'll get the idea.

The scenario is i have a part of a site where users can pick 1 of multiple addresses they have saved. The ID gets generated for each address and I need to apply that ID to a button to submit the form.

I've gotten it so the button receives the ID from the first click, but if I try to select a different address, the ID will not switch. How can I have the button use the ID of the most recently selected radio input? I'm using a data attribute to select this.

```
HTML:
<div>
 <form>
    <input type="radio" data-js="select" id="Test123" /> (id created dynamically)
    <label>Address 1</label>
    <input type="radio" dat-js="select" id="Test124" /> (id created dynamically)
    <label>Address 2</label>
</form>
</div>

<button class="address-continue">Continue</button>

var radioID = $('*[data-js]').attr('id');
var addrContinue = $('.address-continue');

$('*[data-js]').click(function () {
        $(addrContinue).attr('id', radioID);
    });
```

Scenario: user clicks on address 1, so ID is then placed on the button for address 1. user made a mistake, meant to click on address 2. currently when i click address 2, the ID on the button doesn't change. it remains the same as the original click.

I need the ID on the continue button to change based on the proper radio selection.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the relevant markup (HTML).

Comment: Sure. It looks like this (sorry not at my office anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since id is unique use class

```
$('*[data-js]').click(function () {
    var addrButton = $('.address-continue');
    addrButton.removeClass(test123);
    addrButton.removeClass(test124);
    radioID = $('*[data-js]').attr('id');
    addrButton.addClass(radioID);
});
```

Also your basic problem might be because you did not collect your radioID in ur radio function hence it wasn't updated so try this

```
$('*[data-js]').click(function () {
    var radioID = $('*[data-js]').attr('id');
    $(addrContinue).attr('id', radioID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it for you hoping the corresponding elements are in the same order:

```
$('[data-js]').on('change',function() {
  $('.address-continue').data('id', this.id);
});
$('.address-continue').on('click',function() {
  alert( $(this).data('id') );
});
```

You cannot assign a second element in your document the id of another. IDs should be unique; therefore I have used `data-id`.

```js
$('[data-js]').on('change',function() {
  $('.address-continue').data('id', this.id);
});
$('.address-continue').on('click',function() {
  alert( $(this).data('id') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <form>
    <input type="radio" name="address" data-js="select" id="Test123" /> (id created dynamically)
    <label>Address 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="address" data-js="select" id="Test124" /> (id created dynamically)
    <label>Address 2</label>
</form>
</div>

<button class="address-continue">Continue</button>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Since you cannot duplicate IDs you can use `data-id`. What do you want to do with the id once it's copied to the button?

Comment: i need to be able to select an address, attach that ID to the 'continue' button so i can move forward. however i need it to work in the scenario a user accidently clicks the wrong address. that no matter which address (radio button) they select, the continue button will grab the right ID. currently it grabs the first one you selected and will never change.

Comment: You have a typo in your html, and that caused the selector not to work. You have `dat-js` instead of `data-js` in the second `radio`. The code `snippet` should work fine. Let me know.